# where should I add if statement? Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, swiftui

I am complete beginner so I am sorry if my question will sound dumb.. But where should I add the if statement in the actual app? All the tutorials I could find are either from the Xcode playground or aren't helpful at all.. Thanks in advance

I am trying to do something like this: (Basically I want the oneRepMax to be equal to weight if the number of reps is 1)

```swift
if reps == 1 {
    oneRepMax == weight
} else {
    oneRepMax = weight*(1+(0.0333*reps))-2
}
```

Here is my code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  overload
//
//  Created by / on 25.08.2022.
//
 
import SwiftUI
 
 
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var weight = 1.0
    @State private var reps = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Stepper("Reps : \(reps.formatted())", value: $reps, in: 1...10)
            
            TextField("Weight: \(weight.formatted())kg", value: $weight, format: .number)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        
            
            let oneRepMax=weight*(1+(0.0333*reps))-2
 
            Text(String(format: "Your 1RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax, oneRepMax)).padding()
            
            
            Group { 
                Text(String(format: "Your 2RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*2))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*2))+2))                
                    
                Text(String(format: "Your 3RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*3))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*3))+2))
                    
                Text(String(format: "Your 4RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*4))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*4))+2))
                    
                Text(String(format: "Your 5RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*5))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*5))+2))
                    
                Text(String(format: "Your 6RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*6))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*6))+2))
                    
                Text(String(format: "Your 7RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*7))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*7))+2))
                    
                Text(String(format: "Your 8RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*8))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*8))+2))
                    
                Text(String(format: "Your 9RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*9))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*9))+2))
                    
                Text(String(format: "Your 10RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*10))+2, oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*10))+2))   
            }                
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: inside a `Void` like an `onAppear` an `action` of a `Button`, etc. But ideally outside of the `View` completely, all those calculations in the body don't belong either.

Comment: Or you could make it into a computed property in this case since the calculation logic is so simple

Comment: Unrelated but you have **one** placeholder `%.1f` but **two** arguments (with the same value). What's the second argument for? Two answer the question add a function `func computedWeight(factor: Int) -> Double {` and put in the `oneRepMax` constant as well as the expression `oneRepMax/(1 + (0.0333 * factor)) + 2` and return 1 if `reps` is one otherwise the computed value. But be aware that `Double`s are tricky to check for equality.

Comment: try this at the same place: `let oneRepMax = reps == 1.0 ? weight : weight*(1+(0.0333*reps))-2`. It's called a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var weight = 1.0
    @State private var reps = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Stepper("Reps : \(reps.formatted())", value: $reps, in: 1...10)
            TextField("Weight: \(weight.formatted())kg", value: $weight, format: .number)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)

            let oneRepMax = Int(reps) == 1 ? weight : weight*(1+(0.0333*reps))-2  // <-- here

            // -- here, no need for the second oneRepMax...
            Text(String(format: "Your 1RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax)).padding()
            Group {
                // -- here, no need for the second oneRepMax...
                Text(String(format: "Your 2RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*2))+2))
                Text(String(format: "Your 3RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*3))+2))
                Text(String(format: "Your 4RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*4))+2))
                Text(String(format: "Your 5RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*5))+2))
                Text(String(format: "Your 6RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*6))+2))
                Text(String(format: "Your 7RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*7))+2))
                Text(String(format: "Your 8RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*8))+2))
                Text(String(format: "Your 9RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*9))+2))
                Text(String(format: "Your 10RM is %.1f kg", oneRepMax/(1+(0.0333*10))+2))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note the update regarding `Int(reps) == 1`. It's more stable this way.

Comment: Generally, it's a bad practice to create variables inside a `some View` property.

Comment: any supporting evidence on this? It seems that this pattern `if let x = .. {...}` is often used.

Comment: But an `if let` is something quite different in this context imo. If `x` is not nil then show some view …

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create a computed property that returns the result you need, like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var weight = 1.0
    @State private var reps = 1.0
    
    private var oneRepMax: Double {
        if reps == 1 {
            return weight
        } else {
            return weight*(1+(0.0333*reps))-2
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here, every time `ContentView` is redrawn, that is every time one of the `@State` properties changes, the `oneRepMax` property will be recalculated, staying up-to-date.